# Sketch the region whose area is given by the definite integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

Sketch the region whose area is given by the definite integral.
$$ \int_{0}^{{\color{red}6}}\dfrac{x}{{\color{red}8}}\,dx 
$$

I sketched out the correct graph here:
[image: the graph]
And I found the area to be $1/2(b)(h)$, which is $1/2(6)(0.7)=2.1$. Thus, $$ \int_{0}^{{\color{red}6}}\dfrac{x}{{\color{red}8}}\,dx =2.1$$.
I got this answer wrong, can anyone help me where I went wrong?

Comment: Where did you get $0.7$? $\frac68=0.75$, not $0.7$. Everything else is correct.

Comment: ohh, got it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

it represents the area under the line $y=\frac x8$ for $0\le x\le 6$. So draw a line of gradient $\frac18$ and two vertical lines at $x=0$ and $x=6$ and shade the triangle that they contain. It should look something like [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8sb6qbq2pa).

In terms of working it out using are of a triangle, it should be:
$$A=\frac12\times6\times \frac 68$$
as the height at the end is $\frac68$. For the integral:
$$\int_0^6\frac x8dx=\frac12\left[\frac {x^2}8\right]_0^6=\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{6^2}{8}$$